# Boundary value problem for natural convection by shooting method

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, non-linear

I am trying to resolve a special case of boundary value problem which is the boundary layer's equations for natural convection :

[image]

Thanks to a contributor of this forum @LutzLehmann, this set of equations is solved by using the function `solve_bvp` from the scipy library.

Unfortunately, I don't obtain the right result with these particular boundary conditions :
[image]

It seems that the initial guess for the solver doesn't work in this case and I wonder what could suit better.

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Pr = 5

def odesys(t,u):
    F,dF,ddF,θ,dθ = u
    return [dF, ddF, θ-0.25/Pr*(2*dF*dF-3*F*ddF), dθ, 0.75*F*dθ]

def bcs(u0,u1): return [u0[0], u0[1], u1[1], u0[3]-1, u1[3]]

x = np.linspace(0,8,25)
u = [x*x, np.exp(-x), 0*x+1, 1-x, 0*x-1]

res = solve_bvp(odesys,bcs,x,u, tol=1e-5)

print(res.message)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(res.x,res.y[3], color='#801010', label='$\Delta T$')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(res.x,res.y[1], '-', color='C0', label="$F'$")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

And here are the wrong plots obtained :

[image]

Could someone help me by suggesting a better initial case for this problem ?

Thank you for your help,

PS : For the proposition :

```
u = [0.5*x*x*np.exp(-x), x*np.exp(-x), np.exp(-x), np.exp(-x), -np.exp(-x)]
```

I got this :

[image]

Compared to the literature, I am expecting this result (where g is here theta in the set of equations) :

[image]

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes : I've edited the right system now : it is compatible with the code, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I get sensible solutions with interval length `T=18` and initial guess `u = [0.5*x*x*np.exp(-x), x*np.exp(-x), np.exp(-x), np.exp(-x), -np.exp(-x)]`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for this proposition : It is true that the profile obtained of the temperature is correct (Theta) but the profile of `F'` doesn't correspond to what I expect. It's always the same situation : if I got one plot correct the other differs from what expected... The plot obtained are shown in the edit of the initial post.

Comment: Something is wrong then between the equations and the graph. The equations demand that `f(oo)` is negative to have the situation at infinity halfways stable, so that also `f'` will be mainly negative. So perhaps in the plot it really is the graph of `-f'`? But that would also not work, as `Pr=7` gives a maximum of `-f'` of `0.7`, while in the last plot it is at `0.25`. With `Pr=1` I get the maximum at `0.5`, which is the same in the plot. So the scaling is different and depends on `Pr`?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your reply : in fact the quantity `f'` represents the velocity. To answer to the question of the scaling dependency : yes it is, since the equations that I put on my post are only valid for `Pr >= 1` I think that, thanks to your remark, I am realizing that maybe the author of the article where the plot is from, forgot to put a minus sign... Otherwise, the plot obtained is never the same

Comment: @LutzLehmann However, I don't understand why the guess that you proposed (and also the plot obtained) doesn't give the same values for `Pr > 1` since the theory developed is supposed to be valid for this range. The fact that the maximum is `0.7` instead of `0.25` is quite disturbing...

Comment: I will try to investigate : I think it's more a question about physics rather than the code itself : Thank you for your help.